# Simple ng-change not working properly in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I might be missing something stupidly as this simple code doesn't work as expected. What is wrong is the `$scope.change` function in the MainCtrl doesn't work (no alert box popped up).

In a nutshell, the view is (it's in jade, better to view?)

```
<body ng-app="epfApp">
...
label(ng-repeat="question in questions")
    | {{ question.title }}
    input(type="{{question.type}}", ng-change="change()")
```

and in the controller file

```
angular.module('epfApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {

    $scope.questions = {
        '1': {
                'title': 'The first question is?',
                'type': 'text',
                'placeholder': 'first question'
            },

        '2': {
                'title': 'The second question is?',
                'type': 'text',
                'placeholder': 'second question'
            }
    };

    $scope.change = function() {
        $window.alert('text');
    };

});
```

And the route:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  });
```

Now what it is doing properly is that it correctly populates the view with the data created (i.e. the questions json). However, What it is not doing properly is the **`change()`** function bound to the input textbox doesn't work.

What am I missing here? This obviously is a very basic job.

Answer (score 25):

`ng-change` requires `ng-model` as well.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label ng-repeat="question in questions">
        {{question.title}}
        <input type="{{question.type}}" ng-model="question.placeholder" ng-change="change()" />
        <br />
    </label>
</div>
```

[Check out this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zDvD9/)

Answer (score 4):

ng-change not working but it work if you define ng-model="yourValue"... like this

```
<select id="editSelect" ng-model="Option" ng-change="okChange()" name="Option">
    <option ng-repeat="data in Option" value="{{data.Option}}">{{data.Option}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="file" ng-model="image" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage()" />
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in uploadcollection">
     {{item.name}}  ({{item.size}})
   </li>
</ul>
```

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.uploadImage = function () {
        $scope.uploadcollection.push({name: "Income.pdf", size: "10mb"});
        $scope.$apply();
}
$scope.uploadcollection = [{name: "Income.pdf", size: "10mb"}, {name: "Expense.pdf", size: "1.5mb"}];
}
```

I have created a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/fA968/120/

**NOTE:** This Example not worked with v1.4.8: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js

---

**Update**
Here is an simple way to do this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('customOnChange', function() {
return {
 restrict: 'A',
 link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   var onChangeFunc = scope.$eval(attrs.customOnChange);
      element.unbind('change').bind('change', function(e) {
        onChangeFunc(e);
      });
   }
  };
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fA968/199/) is an updated Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

When the expression inside of the `ng-change=""` is something which errors (like with a spelling error) it will not log the error to the console. You will not know anything is amiss except for the fact that nothing happens.

Make sure to spell things correctly and to prefix the alias you give the "Controller As" syntax, if applicable.